# Rename Trackmania tags

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

Today I got the "create tag synonyms" privilege, and now I'm confused about what to do in this case...

There are two TrackMania-related tags in gaming site:

- [`trackmania`](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/trackmania), with 2 questions
- [`trackmania-nations`](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/trackmania-nations), with 3 questions

The first tag is broad, and can be thought as a tag for the entire series. So, **maybe it would be better to rename it to *trackmania-series***, just like other games. Or make *trackmania* a synonym for *trackmania-series*.

However, **the second tag is incorrect**. Although there existed a *TrackMania Nations* game, the questions are actually asking about *TrackMania Nations Forever* game. And, in fact, those questions also apply to *TrackMania United Forever*. So, in my opinion, the correct would be to retag those questions as *trackmania-forever*.

I know this is confusing (and my question here isn't as clear as I would like), but I wanted opinions about what to do in this case.

In my opinion we should change those tags into:

- `trackmania-series` - for all TrackMania games
- `trackmania-forever` - for TrackMania Nations Forever and TrackMania United Forever
- Maybe `trackmania` as a synonym for `trackmania-series`.
- Maybe `trackmania-nations-forever` and `trackmania-united-forever` as synonyms for `trackmania-forever`.

What do you think?

And, considering new TrackMania games will be released "soon", I expect more questions in this site, and I believe it would be better/easier to clean up tags before there are too many questions.

---

#### Information about TrackMania games

[TrackMania series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TrackMania) have many games. Let me try to summarize them:

- *TrackMania*, *TrackMania Original*, *TrackMania Sunrise*, *TrackMania Sunrise Extreme*

  - These are 4 old games.
- *TrackMania Nations* (freeware), *TrackMania United*

  - These are old versions that have been superseded by newer games
- **TrackMania Nations Forever** (freeware), **TrackMania United Forever**

  - These are updated versions of the former games. For previous United owners, the update to Forever version is free.
  - These are the latest versions available for PC, also available on Steam, and also actively played.
  - These versions run on the same engine, share the same files, and people from either game can play together. I can safely say they can be group-called as *TrackMania Forever*.
- **TrackMania DS**, **TrackMania Wii**

  - Console/handheld versions.

So, basically, only the 4 games listed in bold are "current", all 6 other games are old and can be ignored for now. In near future, *TrackMania 2* will be released (as well as *ShootMania* and *QuestMania* in a later date, forming what is called *Mania-Planet*).

(heck! I just noticed [this answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/4612/how-does-the-old-version-of-trackmania-differ-from-trackmania-nations-forever/4633#4633) explained everything better than me)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well spotted. I've retagged all questions to [trackmania-forever](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/trackmania-forever), given that the only questions you can ask about the paid version that do not apply to the free version that I can think of relate to the extra environments... perhaps there's some ground to cover there, but we have no such questions so far.

Nevermind we can't use a tag such as [trackmania-nations-forever](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/trackmania-nations-forever), as it's longer than 25.

Comment: And what should be done to old "trackmania" and "trackmania-nations" tags? They still show up in the tag list.

Comment: @Denilson They should disappear momentarily